# How do I link to a page that is accessed by a tabpanel?

Tags: html, tabpanel

How do I access a tabpanel section from a URL? The "gotcha" for me is that I can't alter the code from the page that I'm accessing, so I believe I need to have the tab link directly in my URL. Below is the page I'm accessing:

https://www.schools.org/support-center

The tabbed section I'm trying to reach is the Contact Us tab. However when I try the URL below it just takes me to the Popular Questions tab. Which is defaulted to active. My question is how can I get to the Contact Us section on that page, with out modifying the code on the page on that page.

https://www.schools.org/support-center#ContactUs-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following link which strips the "-tab" part:

https://www.schools.org/support-center#ContactUs

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Holy crap that worked. I thought I tried that, but I guess not! Anyways, thank you so much for the help.